# How to get REST API followed

Tags: development, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

How to get followed items using REST API (C# and JS)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the follow content in SharePoint using below endpoint:

```
<site url>/_api/social.following
```

Get followed content by using:

```
<site url>/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=14)
```

Find more details in below reference.

**Reference**:

[Follow documents, sites, and tags by using the REST service in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-follow-documents-sites-and-tags-by-using-the-rest-service-in-sharepoint-2)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh :))